# How to access a specific column is csv file? If a cell is empty in that column, do not write row at all in csv file

Tags: java, csv, groovy

Brief summary of work.
I had a zip folder with xml files. I unzipped it, send it to another destination folder. For all the xml files in the folder. I needed to get filename, xpath, a value of a specific element. I did all of that.

What I need to do is access a specific column in the csv file(Labels column), check to see if any cell is empty, if it is empty I do not want to write the entire row at all in the csv file.  Hope I'm clear enough
Its a groovy/java work

```
public void getAllFiles(String fileName) {

    //create csv file in a variable and hold all files in a single variable as well

    def xmlFile = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File(fileName))

    def csvFile = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\test1.csv")

    def labels = xmlFile.breadthFirst().findAll {

        if (it.name() == 'element1') {
             println it
            println it.attributes().get("attribute")
            println getXPath(it)

            def langs = it.attributes().get("attribute")
            def description = it.parent().parent().children().find { node -> node.name() == 'message' }.text().toString()
            def xmlFile2 = new File(fileName)

            csvFile.append('"' + xmlFile2.getName() + '"' + "," + '"' + getXPath(it) + '"' + "," + '"' + description + '"' + "," + '"' + langs + '"' + "," + '"' + it + '"' + "\r\n")
        }
    }
}


def list = []
def ant = new AntBuilder()

ant.unzip(src: "zipfolderpath.zip", dest: "path_to_folder",
overwrite: "false")
def dir = new File("Path_to_folder")
def csvFile = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\test1.csv")
def valueA = "XPATH"
def valueE = "FILENAME"
def valueD = "DESCRIPTION"
def valueB = "LANGUAGE"
def valueC = "LABELS"

csvFile.write("\r\n" + valueE + "," + valueA + "," + valueD + "," + valueB + "," + valueC + "\r\n")
dir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) { file -> 
    if (file.getName().endsWith("xml")) {
        extractFileName(file.absolutePath)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn’t it be enough to check this it variable for null? From what I can understand that’s the Label value in your CSV

Comment: Hi Tomaz, yes it is the label value. But I'm so new to this grrovy and java stuff, I don't know how to write the code to check if the cell is empty, that is where i'm stuck. An example or sample code would help a lot.

Comment: I’m not familiar with Groovy, only Java, so I don’t really know what this it Object contains. When you println it what does it display?

Comment: when i print it, it displays the file name, xpath, a value from an element, and the label values and some empty cell in the label column, then it writes these data in a csvfile with all data under their respective column. The last column which is the label, if its empty I don't want to write the row at all in the csv.